# How to create makefile for program using curses.h

Tags: c, makefile, pdcurses

I am struggling with making a makefile for the sample code below using curses.h.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<curses.h>    

int main(){
WINDOW *initscr(void);
initscr();
int endwin(void);
return 0;
}
```

I included library and header in Netbeans, but when I try to build with makefile:

```
CC=C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -lm -lncurses
DEPS=curses.h
OUTPUT=main

all:
    echo "Building all"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) render.c -o $(OUTPUT)
```

it gives me :

```
echo "Building all"
Building all
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc -std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -lm -lncurses render.c -o main
render.c:3:19: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
 #include<curses.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe": *** [all] Error 1
```

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 150ms)

Comment: It seems the `<curses.h>` file is in a location not searched by default by the compiler. You have to add the `-I` flag to tell the compiler (preprocessor actually) where to find the header file.

Comment: You will probably have similar error with the location of the `ncurses` library as well (and some other problems due to the order in which you place it on the command line). Use the `-L` flag for the linker there.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `<curses.h>`, try `<ncurses.h>`.

Comment: `curses.h` is in project folder and also in lib subfolder

Comment: when I added -I. flag, it gives me:
echo "Building all"
Building all
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc -std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -lm -lncurses -I. render.c -o main
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lncurses
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe": *** [all] Error 1


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 300ms)

Comment: I am working in Windows, so it does not recognize `ncurses.h`

Comment: I tried it with:
`CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -Llib -lpdcurses.lib -lpdcurses.dll -lpanel.h -lcurses.h`
but same result

Comment: You should provide information about what compiler toolchain are you using on Windows. I gues TDM-GCC is based on mingw. Also, please detail on which curses library are you using? To be able to use it, you need two things: the necessary header files (such as curses.h) and the binary libraries (such as ncurses.lib or pdcurses.lib). You should use static linking libraries, that is on Windows .lib versions. With option -L you instruct the compiler in which folders to search for such .lib files while with -l you name a particular library. Please find and tell the location of .lib files.

Comment: Yes, it's mingw_tdm compiler. I am using pdcurses:
[link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/3.4/pdc34dll.zip/download).... and perhaps there is a problem with lib file. This is another error message from NetBeans:
`skipping incompatible lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses`

Answer (score 1):

Just add -I. -L. to your CFLAGS macro, this adds the project library to the search paths of both the preprocessor and linket. This should work provided you have curses header and library files in your project folder. If the header or library files are in different folders just modify -I or -L flags accordingly.

Your last comment suggested that the preprocessing and compilation went fine but the linker could not locate the library file.

As a general note, it would be a good idea to put compiler flags to CFLAGS and linker flags to a different macro, say LDFLAGS.

Macro DEPS should also be used to enable incremental compilation. It is usually used as a dependency to the compilation rule but since you don't have it separately you could put it besides all such as this:

```
all : $(DEPS)
```

Comment: I replaced CFLAGS line with `CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -lm -lcurses -l. -L.`
but i t gives me: Makefile:5: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 60ms)

Comment: Please, write completly, how should it look like. Thanks

Comment: you should use `-I.` not `-l.`

Comment: I can send you my NetBeans project settings.

Comment: OK, or you could paste the complete makefile and directory structure and listing here.

Comment: It would be easier to send pictures (of folder structure and settings) by other means, because I cannot post it here (not enough) reputation.

Comment: `CC=C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc  
 CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -lm -lcurses -I. -L.  
 DEPS=curses.h  

 all:  
     echo "Building all"  
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) render.c -o $(OUTPUT)`

Comment: You should provide information about what compiler toolchain are you using on Windows. I gues TDM-GCC is based on mingw. Also, please detail on which curses library are you using? To be able to use it, you need two things: the necessary header files (such as curses.h) and the binary libraries (such as ncurses.lib or pdcurses.lib). You should use static linking libraries, that is on Windows .lib versions. With option -L you instruct the compiler in which folders to search for such .lib files while with -l you name a particular library. Please find and tell the location of .lib files.

Comment: I found out, that the problem is with the architecture or compiler.
I can make it run on win32 (compiler C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gcc) but not on win64 (C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gcc)
That's why copmpiler says: `skipping incompatible lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses`
Does pdcurses.lib exist for 64 bit architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, it works, but it still returns 8 errors.
Solution to fix 1 of the 8 errors is listed further down.

I cd to the location of thadgavin.c 
( for me it is "pset1/source")

For ubuntu (I used 16.04)

$ cc thadgavin.c -lm -lncurses

$ ./a.out

You can rename a.out to thadgavin (same as "make" would have done if it would have worked).

$ mv a.out thadgavin

There you go, hope this helps resolve the last of the errors.

Note:
There is an easy error fix in main(), you need to specify it as an int first. I believe it is on line 61?

Eg;
"int main()" shows only as "main()" due to "int" being up at the top with the abstracted layout syntax I do not believe it knows it has been called as an int. I may be wrong, hopefully someone else can shed light to this problem.

https://youtu.be/oOUgU0z4qeY

If you solve any of the rest of the errors, please post to my video or email Python253@gmail.com for others to benefit from your solution.

Thank you,
My name is Daniel Paul Evans 
                   .... And this is CS50!